# Geolocation of a tweet

Tags: python, twitter, geolocation, geo, tweepy

I am using Tweepy (python) to access to Twitter Search API, and I am looking to extract the geo-coordinates of the tweet.

As you can see in the screenshot, I found `geo` and `coordinates`, and they are inverted.

I would like to know if I am in the good track first, then how can I distinguish between Latitude & Longitude ?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why all my coordinates are None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**coordinates**" is the official field for this info while the "**geo**" field is deprecated. So ignore the **geo** field. For further details see this discussion http://bit.ly/1sM62oH

Comment: Like @askthewolves said, `coordinates` -80,26->Antarctica, while `geo` 26,-80 ->US. `geo` is more logical! Even if we can find a good wireless connection in Anatactica :-)

Comment: This is the tweet that I streamed: https://twitter.com/ErnestoColon28/status/482705940605833216 
The location is Tamarac, FL (US).

Answer (score 2):

If it's not in Antarctica, the -80.xxxx is longitude. For longitude, the US is like ~79-80ish to ~120 something (I'm approximating). It seems like the first value in 'coordinates':{} is longitude, whereas the first value in 'geo':{} is latitude.

Comment: Yes, I am ok with this. This is already what I've done to verify.. But seeing @WaelBENZID link : http://bit.ly/1sM62oH made me confused.

Comment: What he's saying is the 'geo' field, won't be around forever, so better to use the 'coordinates' field for your app, so that you don't have to rebuild that component when they retire the geo field. Use the **coordinates** field, the first element of which is **longitude**.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that the standard was always (lat,long). I found also this discussion useful https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6919

Answer (score 1):

You would need four data points for a bounding box that can be found from OpenStreetMap. For example the coordinates for Madison is as follows:

```
twitterStream.filter(locations=[-89.566389,42.998071,-89.246452,43.171916]) #Madison, WI
```